# Expand inner div width when horizontally scrolling parent

Tags: css, overflow

I have a sidebar with some lists. Each list is preceded by a title bar `div`. The sidebar has a fixed width and `overflow-x: auto`. Lists content can overflow, making the parent sidebar to show the scroll bar.

The issue is that the title bar `div` doesn´t expand when the scroll bar appears. I would like either, don't move it when scrolling or to expand the 'div' to fit the extra space generated by the scroll bar: [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/wifenav/edit?html,css,output)

Is it possible to resolve this issue using CSS?

Comment: Can you consider some JavaScript based solution?

Comment: Can you please clear your requirement ? Do you want [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nimish/fe6xrbm4/)

Comment: @Nimish Hi, I want only one scrollbar in the sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be its possible with CSS, but in my opinion, you will need to use some JavaScript to fix this issue:

Here is the trick:

```
var sidebar = $('.sidebar');

sidebar.scroll(function(e) {
  sidebar.find('.title').css({
    marginLeft: sidebar.scrollLeft()
  });
});
```

We will add some `margin-left` on the `.title` elements equal to the number of pixels of horizontal scroll. This will always show the title bar stick to the right of the scroll able element.

```js
$(function() {
  var sidebar = $('.sidebar');
  
  sidebar.scroll(function(e) {
    sidebar.find('.title').css({
      marginLeft: sidebar.scrollLeft()
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 160px;
  height: 195px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;  
  text-align: right;
  background-color: grey;
}

.list {
  margin-top: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="title">
    Title
  </div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      This is a very long long line
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="title">
    Title2
  </div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      This is a very long long line
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: nice solution +1

Comment: Thanks, I think I would go for this solution as it doesn't seem posible with CSS only.

Comment: @Ivan You can check my answer if you want to do with Pure CSS

Answer (score 1):

Please find the solution below with CSS only.

```css
.sidebar {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 160px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding-top: 20px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.title {
  width: 160px;
  text-align: right;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: grey;
}

.list {
  margin-top: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<title>
  JS Bin
</title>

<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="title">
      Title
    </div>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>
        This is a very long long line
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear">
      <div class="title">
        Title2
      </div>
      <ul class="list">
        <li>
          This is a very long long line
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear">
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution doesn't play well when there is also a vertical scroll.